# NOT IN clause for LINQ?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I am creating a LINQ query and I want to have a SQL-style NOT IN clause to make sure that my result does not have one of the values from a comma separated list.

I could not find a NOT IN clause for LINQ. Please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 3):

You need to do a !contains on the collection of objects that you want to exclude.

```
var excluded = new[] { 3, 7, 19, 41 };
var v = from i in Enumerable.Range(0, 100)
        where !excluded.Contains(i)
        select i;
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll want the .Except() set operator.

```
var results = list1.Except(list2);
```

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2008/07/12/the-linq-set-operators.aspx
http://www.hookedonlinq.com/ExceptOperator.ashx

Note: You'll have to implement an iEqualityComparor to use the Except method with complex types.

Comment: Except creates the intersection of two containers, it is the right thing to do if both containers contain the same type, but for the general case you need to use !contains.

Comment: Yes, and is the most common case.  Except() provides a much more readable solution, but in some cases is less flexible than Contains().

Answer (score 1):

Something like this...

```
string items = "1,2,3,4";
var subList = items.Split(',');
var result = list.Where(item=>!subList.Contains(item.SomeStringField));
```